# SQL Select Query to pick null value columns followed by record columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a select query to show null value columns in the right hand followed by columns with records. As i have around 50 columns in a table .. i find it difficult to trace which column has null value.

How to write a query which displays null value records followed by data records in a select query.

Comment: Can you show an example of starting data and how you expect the output of the query to be?

Comment: NULL, NULL, NULL, ABC, '10/15/2015', 'COMMENT'      If you look into this first three column has Null value which i moved it to the right and later columns has some data on it ..

Comment: I mean edit the question and add more sample data, not post it in the comments section. It has limited options for formatting